# Downloand images with ASIHttpRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have an XML like this :

```
                        <....
                           <images xmlns:a="http://.../Arrays">
                               <a:string>http://images...233/Detail.jpg</a:string>
                               <a:string>http://images....233/Detail2.jpg</a:string>
                           </images>
                       .../>
```

i would like to dowload all the images and put it in my tableviewCell usig ASIHttpRequest. How i can do this please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you should parse all the url of image.

You can create a costom uiview, each view have a http request, when the http request finished, draw the image data to the view.